# Angle and distance between subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, perturbation-theory

Let $\text{Sin}(\Theta)$ be the diagonal matrix containing the $Sine$'s of principal angles between two subspaces $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, and let $\Pi_A$ and $\Pi_B$ be their respective projectors. How do I show that $\|\text{Sin}(\Theta)\| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\|\Pi_A - \Pi_B\|$ (where $\|\cdot\|$ is the spectral norm)?

Edit: the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ factor should not be there as per the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to obtain a slightly different result. In particular, I think that the factor of $\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}$ should not be there.

I will focus on the case that both subspaces are $\ell$-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb C^n$ with $2 \ell \leq n$. Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* proves this result (rather, sets up an exercise in which one may prove this result) by using the following consequence of the existence of the [CS-decomposition](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/Computing.Cs.Gen.Sing.Value.Decomp.pdf).

> **Theorem VII.1.8:** Let $X,Y$ be $n \times \ell$ matrices with orthonormal columns. Then there exist $\ell \times \ell$ unitary matrices $U,V$ and an $n \times n$ unitary matrix $Q$ with the following properties.
>
> If $2\ell \leq n,$ then
>
> $$
> QX U = \pmatrix{I_\ell \\ 0\\0}, \quad QY V = \pmatrix{C \\ S\\ 0}
> $$
> where $C,S$ are diagonal matrices with diagonal entries $0 \leq c_1 \leq \cdots \leq c_\ell \leq 1$ and $1 \geq s_1 \geq \cdots \geq s_\ell \geq 0$ (respectively) and $C^2 + S^2 = I$.

There is also a version of this theorem for the case that $2\ell > n$ which I am ignoring for the purposes of my answer. Now, suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have columns that form orthonormal bases for $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$ respectively. Let $Q,U,V$ be as in the above theorem. Let $\mathcal A',\mathcal B'$ denote the images of $\mathcal A,\mathcal B$ respectively under $Q$. That is, $\mathcal A' = \{Qx : x \in \mathcal A\}$, and $\mathcal B'$ is defined similarly.

Note that the columns of $QXU$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal A'$, and the columns of $QYV$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal B'$. Moreover, the principal angles between $\mathcal A'$ and $\mathcal B'$ must be equal to those between $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$. With that, we can see that $S = \sin(\Theta)$, as you have defined it.

Now, we note that $\Pi_{\mathcal A} = XX^*$, so that
\begin{align}
\left\|\Pi_{\mathcal A} - \Pi_{\mathcal B} \right\| & = 
\left\|XX^* - YY^* \right\| 
\\ & = 
\left\|Q(XX^* - YY^*)Q^* \right\|
\\ & = 
\left\|(QXU)(QXU)^* - (QYV)(QYV)^* \right\|
\\ & = 
\left\|\pmatrix{I_\ell & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0} - \pmatrix{C^2 & CS& 0\\CS & S^2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0} \right\|
\\ & =
\left\|\pmatrix{I - C^2 & -CS & 0\\ -CS & -S^2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0}\right\|
= \left\|\pmatrix{S^2 & -CS & 0\\ -CS & -S^2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0}\right\|.
\end{align}
So, we now need to compute the spectral norm of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{S^2 & -CS\\ -CS & -S^2}.
$$
We see that there is a permutation-similarity between this matrix and the block-diagonal matrix
$$
\pmatrix{M_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && M_\ell}, \quad M_k = s_k\pmatrix{s_k & -c_k\\ -c_k & -s_k}, \quad k = 1,\dots,\ell.
$$
We see that $M_k$ is $s_k$ multiplied by an orthogonal matrix, which means that we have $\|M_k\| = s_k$. Thus, we conclude that $\|\Pi_{\mathcal A} - \Pi_{\mathcal B}\|$ is equal to $\max_{k = 1,\dots,\ell} s_k$, which coincides with $\|S\| = \|\sin(\Theta)\|,$ which was what we wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben! Could you, please, clarify why you chose $2\ell\leq n$? You said that there is a version of CS decomposition that works for the other case, too. So, does the proof for that case utilise that version of CS decomposition? Or is it just more complicated?

Comment: @Vikrant A version of this theorem, which is in turn a consequence of the CS decomposition. The difference is that in the case of $2\ell > n$, we'll have
$$
QXU = \pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & I\\ 0 & 0}, \quad QYV = \pmatrix{C & 0\\ 0 & I\\ S & 0}.
$$
In other words, the subspaces will necessarily intersect, which means that some of the principal values angles be zero.

Comment: @Vikrant In any case, we can reduce that situation back to the case where $2\ell \leq n$ by noting that 
$$
\|\Pi_A - \Pi_B\| = \|(I - \Pi_A) - (I - \Pi_B)\|.
$$

Comment: @Vikrant A thought occurs to me: if you already have a definition of principal angles (and the associated principal vectors), then you can probably derive the theorem that I use directly without appealing to the existence of the CS decomposition

Comment: Okay, could you clarify how?

Comment: @Vikrant Well you wouldn't get the theorem, but you'd get close enough for the purposes of the proof. In particular, you could build matrices $X,Y$ whose columns are the principal vectors for $\mathcal {A,B}$, then write these matrices in the form
$$
X = Q \pmatrix{I\\0\\0}, \quad Y = Q \pmatrix{C\\S\\0}
$$
by taking $Q$ to be an orthogonal column whose columns consist of the principal vectors of $\mathcal A$, followed by the orthogonal components of the principal vectors of $\mathcal B$, followed by an extension of this set to an orthonormal basis.